# Строковые ресуры

Tags: java, android

Каким образом не зная точного количества аргументов, создать динамическую строку в ресурсах, чтобы она заполнилась этими аргументами?

Т.е:

```
    <plurals name="numbers">
    <item quantity="one">Я пойду в магазин "%1$s".</item> // понятно как
    <item quantity="few">Я пойду в эти магазины ??? </item> // что нужно поставить вместо ???
    </plurals>
```

и после в коде

```
        if (shops.size() == 1) {
        message = context.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.numbers, 1, events.get(0).getTitle());
        } else {
        // что-то сделать
        }
```

Comment: я может не правильно Вас понял, но я бы просто конкатинировал во втором случае строки нужными значениям. То есть брал строку из strings.xml, после чего в само коде в блоке else добавлял нужные строки.

Comment: @mamba0767  сделал также, но хотелось знать есть ли способ сделать это с помощью строковых констант

Comment: на сколько я знаю, могу ошибаться, но данный механизм аналогичен взаимодействию String.format который подробно [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) описан. Для String.format возможности использовать массив данных или динамическое число элементов - нет. Но во первых - возможно в xml используется другой механизм и нужно лезть в документацию android, либо все таки есть другой способ. Самому было бы крайне интересно - есть ли такая возможность или нет. Возможно стоит поискать информацию в методе Activity.getString(int resId, Object... formatArgs)